# Android: Record and Playback audio from different devices

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, audiotrack, audiorecord

I'm trying to record and play audio using different devices with `AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` and setting `preferredDevice` to set the devices to each.

```
    audioRecord = AudioRecord(
                            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                            sampleRate,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,
                            frameSize * Float.SIZE_BYTES
                        )
    audioRecord?.preferredDevice = mic

    audioTrack = AudioTrack.Builder()
                    .setAudioAttributes(
                        AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .setAudioFormat(
                        AudioFormat.Builder()
                            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT)
                            .setSampleRate(PLAYBACK_SAMPLE_RATE)
                            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
                            .build()
                    )
                    .setBufferSizeInBytes(frameSize * Float.SIZE_BYTES * 2)
                    .build()

    audioTrack?.preferredDevice = speaker
```

It works fine when both input and out are preferred to one device, but when selecting different devices, the mic(`AudioRecord`) is also using the speaker's preferred device. Even when I log the `audioRecord?.routedDevice`, it doesn't seem to change to the preferred device for `AudioRecord` but uses the same preferred `AudioTrack`.

Note: I'm trying to switch between a Wired headset, a Bluetooth device and the Android device's default audio hardware.

Any idea what could be the issue here? Or is it not possible to use two devices for input and output like in iOS?

Comment: Using different audio devices for input (AudioRecord) and output (AudioTrack) on Android is challenging. It may not always work as expected due to device limitations. Explore alternative approaches or third-party libraries for better control, or consider cross-platform solutions like React Native or Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `setPreferredDevice` returns true.

It returns false if the specified `AudioDeviceInfo` is non-null and does not correspond to a valid audio input/output device.

I assumed `mic` and `speaker` is not null because if `deviceInfo` is null, default routing is restored.

Comment: Hey, I have checked that and it always returns true.